# Symfony 4 : Call to a member function get() on null

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

```
class EtudiantController extends AbstractController
{

    private $etudiant ;
    private  $form ;

    public function  __construct()
    {
        $this->etudiant = new Etudiant();
        $this->form = $this->createForm(EtudiantType::class, new Etudiant());

    }
}
```

** i'v got an error when instantiate a form in a constructor using the `createForm()` function **[image]

Comment: Why are you setting $this->etudiant but not using it in your createForm ? You should use it instead of new Etudiant()

Comment: The container is not available in the constructor of a controller hence createForm will fail.  You can take a look at the code and see why.  Create your form in an action.

Comment: how can i create a form in a constructor , that's the question i was searching the whole day

Comment: If you really really really want to do that (which you really really really don't) then either inject the container or inject the form factory service and copy/paste the relevant code from ControllerTrait::createForm().  But again, there is no relevant reason for doing this.  Perhaps you could explain why you think you need this capability?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the wrong way to solve your problem:

```
class EtudiantController extends AbstractController
{
    private $form;

    public function __construct(FormFactoryInterface $formFactory)
    {
        $this->form = $formFactory->create(TextType::class, new Etudiant());
    }
}
```

I say it is wrong (even though it will work) because creating things like forms really should be done in individual controller actions, not hidden in the constructor.  You might be trying to apply Dont Repeat Yourself (DRY) but in cases like this, Don't Confuse Your Future Self takes precedence.

And as far as why injecting the form factory is necessary, I would once again urge you to look at the Symfony source code for AbstractController as well as ControllerTrait.  Understanding how dependency injection works is critical to being able to effectively use the framework.